# How to return a property of an object passed in a parameter?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to read email message Subject and store it as a variable.

For test purposes I have set it to be used as file name for text file.

My code returns an empty string.

1. I send an email to email address where below code is present in `ThisOutlookSession`
2. email Subject is `Topic (923832)`
3. Code performs without errors
4. Text file name is empty

Why is `str = oMail.Subject` not able to read anything?

Here is my code: (`On Error Resume Next` now removed.)

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  ' instantiate objects declared WithEvents
  Set olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim str As String
    Dim openPos As Integer
    Dim closePos As Integer
    Dim midBit As String
    Dim strFolderPath

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strFolderPath & midBit & ".txt")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strFolderPath = "C:\temp\Attachments\"
    str = oMail.Subject

    openPos = InStr(str, "(")
    closePos = InStr(str, ")")

    If oMail.SenderEmailAddress = "username@mail.com" Then

        If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

            midBit = Mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)

            oFile.WriteLine midBit
            oFile.Close

        End If

    End If

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You `Dim` oMail, but you never set it to anything.

Comment: `If Item.SenderEmailAddress = "username@mail.com" Then` `str = Item.Subject`

Comment: Stop using `On Error Resume Next` until you know how, that just hides errors.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: What is exactly Off topic here? Can somebody describe? BTW thanks to everyone! I have my robot up and running now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Use the `ByVal Item As Object` Not `oMail As Outlook.MailItem`*

```
Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

    End If


End Sub
```